# When I complete the actions in Upload window (Using AutoIT) and move to Firefox browser the remaining actions are not working.

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoit

In a form, I upload a document and I click submit.
I used AutoIT tool to automate the windows based actions and to submit I followed the selenium.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Users/MSTEMP/Documents/AutoIT/firefoxupload");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("submitbtn")).click();
```

When I run the above two lines separately it works perfectly but When I merge and run the two lines it fail. How can I reach to workout.

Comment: after line Runtime.getRuntime() plz also close that exe than call driver.findelement....

Comment: Yes I closed and then only the next line is called. It works when I use **Thread.Sleep(3000);** in between the lines.
Apart from this, is there any other alternate solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Hi yes plz use Expected Conditions like below

```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("submitbtn")));
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("submitbtn")).click();
```

Comment: I didn't get any error. It keep on waiting for the element.

Comment: yes do one thing run with above and wait till it errors out as i am sure if it not cliks then it will error out after 30 seconds

Comment: m still waiting for your reply